# Paperclip with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip for uploading files. Does anybody have use it with sidekiq for background jobs?

I was trying to achieve something similar to railscast 383 (uploading to Amazon S3) but with paperclip and sidekiq.

I didn't find too much information for using it with sidekiq and I am thinking if I should change to carrierwave or if there is any example for paperclip and sidekiq (not with FancyUploader and delayed_jobs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `delayed_paperclip` gem:
https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/

According to the gem it has a nice ActiveRecord api so you can do something like:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

   process_in_background :avatar
 end
```